# Como escolher entre os tipos de NoSQL?

Tags: nosql

Os bancos de dados NoSQL tem diferentes tipos básicos:

1. Column based
2. Key-value database
3. Graph-based
4. Document based database

Quais são as diferenças entre esses tipos e como escolher entre eles?

Comment: A pergunta está muito ampla. Cada um tem as suas particularidades bem como os BDs relacionais. Inclusive o fato de usar ou não BD NoSQL. Seja mais específico na sua pergunta, exponha um problema, que a comunidade ajuda a resolve-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [Han2014](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/38476517/06106531.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1504623125&Signature=tEgjx9WAmyd7rLPdSp5ObcWL6wE%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DSurvey_on_NoSQL_Database_PCN_and_CAD_Cen.pdf) os modelos podem ser descritos assim:

Key-value: Significa que cada valor possui uma chave correspondente. Esse modelo suporta operações altamente concorrentes, escalabilidade horizontal (scale out) e consultas. (Além de operações map-reduce)

DBs com essa arquitetura: [Redis](https://redis.io/), [Tokyo-Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/) e Flaris.

Collumn-oriented: Os dados são armazenados em colunas, ao invés de linhas, e os dados são armazenados separadamente para cada coluna. Cada coluna é tratada como um processo diferente. Ideal para sistemas distribuídos.

DBs com essa arquitetura: [Facebook Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), [Hypertable](http://www.hypertable.com/)

Document-based: Tem uma estrutura similar ao Key-value, entretanto cada valor tem um significado semântico armazenado em JSON ou XML. Permite a geração de índices secundários.

DBs com essa arquitetura: MongoDB e CouncheDB.

O Graph-based, segundo minha pesquisa, [é considerado uma outra abordagem](https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-db-vs-nosql/), usada quando são necessários outros pontos de vista sobre os dados. Como o NoSQL trabalha por agregação ele tem uma perspectiva limitada.

A escolha de um modelo ou outro depende das características do seu trabalho e só você pode mensurar isso analisando os prós e os contras de cada modelo. O artigo citado no início pode ser um bom ponto de partida para isso.